# How to check css in unit test

Tags: css, unit-testing

```
 describe('Link', () => {

 makeElement = () => {

  let element = angular.element('<textarea id="addnote" vnc-auto-resize style="height: 0px"></textarea>');
  _$compile_(element)($rootScope);
  return element;
};
// Link specs
it('height should be define and enable', () => {
  let element = makeElement();
  expect(element).to.have.height(30px');
});

  });
```

this return error on height.
how to check height in unit test ?

Comment: @Andrei M : thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to try to use chai-jquery

please install using npm install chai-jquery --save

and change your code to

expect(element).to.have.css('height', 30'px');

thanks

Comment: Ask it by comment, this is not answer.

Comment: Please post it as a comment

Comment: @sumair: ya i am using chai-jquery but still error occur.